# What permissions to host website for OS X Server?

Tags: macos, permission, server.app, apache

I am trying to install Dropplet on my Mavericks Server. I have created the site in Server and copied the files to the root directory.

When I go to configure it, I get the following error, "It seems that your config folder is not writable, please add the necessary permissions.".

I believe it comes from this line,

```
// Check if the install directory is writable.
$is_writable = (TRUE == is_writable(dirname(__FILE__) . '/'));
```

I have searched all over for what owner/group/permissions are needed for a website so Apache can write to it.

Anyone encountered this?

Comment: Maybe reading through this might solve your problem.
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114037/does-apache-require-special-settings-to-run-a-command

Answer (score -2):

This seems to have worked: http://francoisdeschenes.com/2013/02/26/enable-write-permissions-for-apache-built-into-mac-os-x

Strange that this is not on by default?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This answer's link is dead - @jherran is correct in saying that copy-pasting would have been better!